# Multiple words in argument and .upper()

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Code in question:

```
@bot.command()
async def plugins(ctx, *args):

    arg = arg.upper()
    if arg == 'LIST':
        embed = discord.Embed()
        embed.set_author(name='Chicken Bot', icon_url=image_url)
        embed.add_field(name='Plugins List', value= '**Server 1**\n Admin Toolbox\n Common Utilities\n PFE\n Chopper Drop\n UAFK\n \n **Server 2**\n Admin Toolbox\n Common Utilities\n PFE\n Chopper Drop\n Ultimate AFK\n Buddy\n SCP Swap\n Tranq Gun\n Stalky 106\n Better 939\n SCP 575\n Better Sinkholes\n \n Do c!plugins (Plugin Name) for more info!')
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

I would like to make it so that I can have multiple words in an argument AND have those words automatically translated to uppercase. How would I do this as I cannot put `*args = *args.upper()`.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: `args` is a tuple; work with it as you would any other tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `list(map(lambda a: a.upper(), args))`

Here's a full example:

```py
def toUpper(*args):
    upper = list(map(lambda a: a.upper(), args))
    return upper

print(toUpper("hello", "there"))
```

Essentially, when you want `args` as a list, don't use an asterisk.

Comment: I've tried this here: 
 args = list(map(lambda a: a.upper(), args))


But it doesn't seem to work. I'm quite new to Python so I'm sorry for any errors haha. Thank you for your time.

Comment: what error are you getting? The code in the answer will run.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting. https://gyazo.com/2a2f23bd9c5391ae43ca9a86bec14854

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but I'm getting this error now. https://gyazo.com/ddd2e4abe3271bde64cd8ed1a2559ce2

Comment: This is my code here, I've probably just made a silly mistake. https://gyazo.com/d7c7a8530814f1c000a6705efc687d0a

Comment: what does args look like when you print it?

Comment: Here is what happens when I print arg and args. https://gyazo.com/dbd00285f2485a87aae177d59d2730c9